# Reflection.Emit Passing an array as a parameter to a method

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm trying to make a setter in IL emit, but this setter must only accept strings which are in my "array", if not, it must throw an exception. I'm having trouble passing my array to be read in my checkIfAccept method, I'm sure I'm missing an instruction which stores my array pointer in some arg but I have no idea which is.
Thanks in advance and sorry for the noob question.

```
class Accept
{
    public void CreateIL(ILGenerator il, FieldBuilder field, string [] array)
    {
        il.Emit(?);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);  // Push "value" on the stack
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2); // suposed to push my array
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Accept).GetMethod("checkIfAccept"));

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);   // Set the field "_Name" to "value"
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }

    public void checkIfAccept(string obj, string [] array)
    {
        foreach(string str in array)
            if (str != obj) throw new MyException();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to do this directly. The fastest way i can think of is probably a static field somewhere. Then you can store it there and emit il to load it later ( `ldsfld` ).

Comment: This is a really round-about way to validate data. However, if you *really* want to do it this way, you'd have to iterate the array in `CreateIL`, and emit IL which creates and fills an array with the array you've passed. Write a `set` method doing what you want (hard-code the array for now), decompile it, and simulate that - subbing in the hardcoded array for what you've been passed

Comment: Something along the lines of:   `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, array.Length);
  il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr);
  for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
  {
   il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, i);
   il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, array[i]);
   il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
        }`

Comment: @Rob If I did that I would have to change my IfAccept parameters to something like: "public void checkIfAccept(string obj, params string [] par)" right?

Comment: @AndréMoura What makes you think that? It should work as is

Comment: @Rob I thought if I iterated  my array in IL and loaded the strings in args when I called my method I would have to pass an x number of strings, ant not the array reference. And what do you think about thehenny solution? It seems simple.

Comment: @AndréMoura Rob's code is not passing each string to the method, it's recreating the array. Also, `params` is just a sleight of hand, in IL, it does not really exist and you still have to pass an array to a `params` method.